# Error type `bool` cannot be dereferenced in rust to Vector of structs in Rust lang

Tags: rust, reference

I'm making a maze algorithm using rust and wasm and I have two structs. A maze, and maze has an Vec of a Block struct.

Like this:

```rust
pub struct Maze {
    pub cols: usize,
    pub rows: usize,
    pub blocks: Vec<Block>,
    pub stack: Vec<usize>,
}

impl Maze {
    pub fn new(cols: usize, rows: usize) -> Maze {
        let mut maze = Maze {
            cols,
            rows,
            blocks: vec![],
        };

        for y in 0..rows {
            for x in 0..cols {
                maze.blocks.push(Block::new(x, y))
            }
        }

        maze
    }
```

And the struct Block has an attribute called `visited`.
I want in a struct function of Maze change this value

```rust
// in Maze struct impl
    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        let current_index = self.get_current_index();
        let mut current_block = &mut &self.blocks[current_index];

        // .....
        *current_block.visited = true;
```

In the last line occur an error:

```
error[E0614]: type `bool` cannot be dereferenced
   --> src/maze.rs:119:17
    |
119 |                 *current_block.visited = true;
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I do to change this value?

This is my implementation of Block

```rust
pub struct Block {
    pub x: usize,
    pub y: usize,
    pub visited: bool,
}

impl Block {
    pub fn new(x: usize, y: usize) -> Block {
        Block {
            x,
            y,
            visited: false,
        }
    }
```

How can I do to change the `visited` value from `Maze.run`?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems, one which is the error you see and one which you will encounter next. The problem with

```rust
*current_block.visited = true;
```

is that the precedence of `*` is lower than `.`, so you've written code equivalent to)

```rust
*(current_block.visited) = true;
```

which does not compile because the type of the `visited` field is `bool`, which indeed cannot be dereferenced. You could write

```rust
(*current_block).visited = true;
```

and that would work, but it's also unnecessary, because in Rust the `.` operator looks through references, so you only need

```rust
current_block.visited = true;
```

to assign to the `visited` field of an `&mut Block`.

The second problem is that you have an extra `&` here:

```rust
let mut current_block = &mut &self.blocks[current_index];
```

This means `current_block` is of type `&mut &Block`. You can never mutate through an `&` reference, so you need to remove the `&`, and it is not needed anyway:

```rust
let mut current_block = &mut self.blocks[current_index];
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation :)
Worked here, but, this created another problem.
I'll comment bellow

Comment: I have another line getting the new direction that uses the &self.blocks

First: let mut current_block = &mut self.blocks[current_index];

let next_block = match value {
    DIRECTION::UP => &self.blocks[current_index - self.cols],

When I remove the reference to &self.blocks I borrowed. The line getting `next_block` returns error:

immutable borrow occurs here -> &mut self.blocks[current_index].

Comment: @RenatoCassino It's not really feasible to debug further things with the info that can fit in a comment, and it's also not how Stack Overflow works. If you want help getting your code to a fully working state, **include enough code in the question** (the next time you post a question, not this one) that it's possible to compile once the problems are fixed, rather than leaving things like `next_block` out.